# How to list imports within a Python module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is get a list of module objects that represent the imports within a specific module, e.g. via inspection/reflection. I can get the global list of imports but this doesn't tell me which module is using which other modules.

To be clear, I'm talking about modules *in* Python, not packages as installed by PIP. I'm looking for code entirely in Python 2.7 to take a module reference (say `sys.modules['foo']`) and return a `list` of that module's imports as either name, path, or another module object. (All I actually want right now is the path.)

```
import sys
for module_name in sys.modules:
   print "Modules imported by %s are: ..." % (module_name,)
```

How would you complete the above snippet to actually list the imports?

Comment: Check out [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs).

Comment: @Brobin: I must have been unclear, I mean Python modules *not* PIP packages.

Comment: Gotcha. Perhaps [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`modulefinder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) package from the standard library.

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('my_script.py')

for name, mod in finder.modules.iteritems():
    print(name)
```