# How to get a list of modules imported by a python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I want to access some kind of import dependency tracking in Python, if there is any.

I decided to add to my module a `__dependencies__` dict describing versions of all modules imported by the module.

I want to have an automated way of obtaining a list of modules imported by my module. Preferably in the last line of the module.

[`ModuleFinder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html) (as suggested by [How to list imports within a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165584/how-to-list-imports-within-a-python-module) ) would not work since the inspection shall be performed for already loaded module.

Another problem with `ModuleFinder` is that it inspects a Python **script** (with `if __name__ == '__main__'` branch), not a module.

If we consider a toy script script.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import foo
```

then the result is:

```
>>> mf = ModuleFinder
>>> mf.run_script('script.py')
>>> 'foo' in mf.modules
True
```

which should be False if script is imported as a module.

I do not want to list all imported modules - only modules imported by my module - so `sys.modules` (suggested by [What is the best way of listing all imported modules in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236052/what-is-the-best-way-of-listing-all-imported-modules-in-python)) would return too much.

I may compare snapshots of `sys.modules` from the beginning and the end of the module code. But that way I would miss all modules used by my module, but imported before by any other module.

It is important to list also modules from which the module imports objects.

If we consider a toy module example.py:

```
from foo import bar
import baz
```

then the result should be like:

```
>>> import example
>>> moduleImports(example)
{'foo': <module 'foo' from ... >,
 'baz': <module 'baz' from ...>}
```

(it may contain also modules imported recursively or `foo.bar` given bar is a module).

Use of `globls()` (according to [How to list imported modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858100/how-to-list-imported-modules?noredirect=1&lq=1)) requires me to deal with non-module imports manually, like:

```
from foo import bar
import bar
```

How can I avoid that?

There is another issue with my solution so far. PyCharm tends to clean up my manual imports on refactoring, which makes it hard to keep it working.

Comment: It's not clear why you think `ModuleFinder` would not work. In fact, it surely must be the only thing that *could* possibly work. How else are you going to distinguish between modules that were already loaded and ones that were first imported by your module? And how would you identify imports that are not in the module-global scope (e.g. inside functions)?

Comment: @ekhumoro I have no idea why SO has not informed me about your comment. See the edited question, then please let me know so I can remove [EDIT] tags.

Comment: Your claim that `ModuleFinder` does not work with modules is obviously false - see the [example in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/modulefinder.html#example-usage-of-modulefinder). I don't see any other good reasons why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Can you give a better example?

Comment: @ekhumoro Please point the example importing the module, then passing the imported module (not a `str`) to the `ModuleFinder`. I can not see it.
Also, please see the updated question - I added an example of `ModuleFinder` failure at "__main__" branch.

Comment: @abukaj. It makes no sense at all to pass an already imported module. As I pointed out in my first comment, if you did that, there would be no way to detect imports that were already in `sys.modules`, or not in the module-global scope. Also, there is no failure in your example - `ModuleFinder` correctly finds all the imports in the given python code. The only issue is how to explicitly treat a file as a module. Unfortunately, `run_script` doesn't allow passing in a file object, which would provide an easy work-around. However, the undocumented `load_module` method does allow that.

Comment: @ekhumoro That is great that `ModuleFinder` does what it is intended to do. However it is not what I want to do. See the first line of the question now.

Comment: @abukaj. Your question remains unclear. The requirement that this must work for an "already loaded module" makes no sense, and is contradicted by the rest of your question. Do you really expect to obtain this information *after* all the importing has already been done? Your own current solution does not work that way.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, I expect there is a some kind of import tracking in Python. Also as an author of the module I am fine with injecting into my module some of inspection code.

Comment: @abukaj. No, there is no such import tracking. If there was, what would be the purpose of `ModuleFinder`? Putting inspection code into the module doesn't seem feasible - surely such code would have to perform its own imports? I think there must be very good reasons why `ModuleFinder` works the way it does.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) moudule

For example:

```
import inspect
import os
m = inspect.getmembers(os) # get module content
filter(lambda x: inspect.ismodule(x[1]), m) # filter dependant modules
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/NgsN/0)

If you want the local modules imported just use:

```
filter(lambda x: inspect.ismodule(x[1]), locals().items()) # filter dependant modules
```

Another [live example](https://repl.it/Ngt2/0)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it has the same disadvantage that my current solution(filtering `globals()`). It omits non-module imports (in case of `from foo import bar` `foo` goes unnoticed).

Comment: @abukaj, i dont think you are gonna get that unless manually specified, because actually foo is not in use since python is not bringing it to scope :/

Comment: I was hoping there is some kind of import tracking in Python modules.

Comment: live examples are broken.

Comment: you can pass the predicate to `getmembers`, i.e. `inspect.getmembers(os, inspect.ismodule)`